# Supported Linux OS version for Anthos GKE on-prem

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, rhel

I am referring to https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/how-to/install-overview-basic to install GKE on-prem by referring to https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/how-to/vsphere-requirements-basic.

I will appreciate it if you can let me know the supported Linux OS version which needs to be installed as part of the Anthos GKE on-prem setup using VMware's vSphere Server Virtualization.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,

Kaushal

Answer (score 0):

> GKE on-prem cluster nodes run Ubuntu version 18.04 (bionic)

Quoting from the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/concepts/node-image).

Comment: Are they going to support RHEL/CentOS Linux OS in GKE on-prem cluster nodes?

Comment: I don't know this. The best would be to ask a [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#support) directly.

Comment: @Kaushal are you able to install anthos gke on-prem

Answer (score 0):

while creating you should have to follow below constraints ->

```
image-family=ubuntu-2004-lts --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
boot-disk-size 200G
boot-disk-type pd-ssd
tags http-server,https-server
min-cpu-platform "Intel Haswell"
```